# Filtering out multidimensional data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a TestF.csv file containing following lines.

```
id,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7
1,9.44,9.32,8.52,7.52,8.19,10.07,10.86
2,-1.89,-4.41,-3.06,3.65,5.95,9.07,10.99
3,9.36,7.51,7.68,7.33,6.7,8.84,45.31
4,6.36,6.51,7.8,8.53,7.7,8.9,35.0
```

I would like to filter out the rows, for which values of D1 through D7 are in a specific range.
For example, for a 5 < value < 40, rows returned by the code are,

```
id,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7
1,9.44,9.32,8.52,7.52,8.19,10.07,10.86
4,6.36,6.51,7.8,8.53,7.7,8.9,35.0
```

Following code by me works but it only checks the value of D1 if it is in the range but not other values.

```
queue()
     .defer(d3.csv,"data/TestF.csv")
    .await(ready);

    test.forEach(function(d) {
    for (var i = 0, n = 8, c; i < n; ++i) {
        d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
    }
    });

    testFiltered = test.filter(function(d) {
    for (var i = 1, n = 8, c; i < n; ++i) {
        return (d[c = columns[i]] >= 5 && d[c = columns[i]] <= 40);
    }
})
```

What changes will result in making the code work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a row conversion function (in your case, in the `defer` method that contains `d3.csv`). It can be just this:

```
const row = (d, _, columns) => columns.slice(1).every(e => d[e] > 5 && d[e] < 40) ? d : null;
```

As you can see, we get all columns except the first (`slice(1)`) and test them with your values, returning the object (`d`) if they pass.

Here is the demo:

```js
const csv = `id,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7
1,9.44,9.32,8.52,7.52,8.19,10.07,10.86
2,-1.89,-4.41,-3.06,3.65,5.95,9.07,10.99
3,9.36,7.51,7.68,7.33,6.7,8.84,45.31
4,6.36,6.51,7.8,8.53,7.7,8.9,35.0`;

const row = (d, i, columns) => columns.slice(1).every(e => d[e] > 5 && d[e] < 40) ? d : null;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, row);

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Does the code check for values in first column also? It is not clear to me - 'except the first (slice(1))'. I will test it though and will let you know.

Comment: Sorry but , i could not use it. I am looking for creating subset of data after reading csv file not while reading the file.